# gdb corefile not see function parameters

Tags: c++, exception, gdb, coredump, stack-frame

My application crashed due to uncaught exception (my c++ code throws uncaught exception under certain condition).  I am trying to gdb the corefile. The binary library is "not striped". And the stack trace shows the function (my code) from which an uncaught exception is thrown, but when I try to print the function arguments, I always get "no symbol xxx in current context". info args also return "No symbol table info available".

Can anyone shed a light why ? is it due to the uncaught exception which unwind/corrupts the stack ?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: A coredump will not necessarily contain all the symbols. This can be due to missing libraries or non-debug built libraries or even compiler optimisation.

Comment: Also you should try to firs [search stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gdb+No+symbol+table+info+available) before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your binary lacks debug info.

If you built it with `gcc`, and want to debug the `core` you already have (if e.g. it's hard to reproduce the crash), you *may* be able to recover from this by rebuilding the binary with *exactly* the same source and command lines, adding `-g` to compile and link commands. (Note: you *must* use the same compile lines; replacing `-O2` with `-g` wouldn't do.)

If the crash is not hard to reproduce, simply rebuild the binary with `-g -O0`, run it under GDB, and enjoy "easy" debugging.

> The binary library is "not striped".

This doesn't mean what you think it means. Not stripped means that the symbol table is still present in the binary.

GDB will read this symbol table, and use it to map ranges of addresses to function names.

But to recover names and values of local variables and parameters, you *must* compile with debug info (which is what `-g` flag does for most compilers).

Comment: Should the optimization flag also be lowered?

Comment: @dlmeetei Not if you want to analyze already existing `core` file.

Comment: But we are asking to recompile

Comment: @dlmeetei Yes. So? Rebuilding the binary with the *exact* same sources and command lines, with addition of `-g`, *often* allows one to analyze a `core` produced by non-debug binary. That's *the* point of my answer.

Comment: got it. I usually lower my optimization flags also when compiling with -g